# docker-compose trouble connecting to postgres server

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Java Spring boot application. Following are my dockerfile and docker-compose file

```
COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

COPY ./src ./src
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
WORKDIR /my-project

COPY --from=maven target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./
CMD ["java", "-jar", "./demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker

  web:
    build: .
    links:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
    depends_on:
      - db
```

when I run `docker-compose up`, I am getting following error:

```
web_1  | 2020-10-07 14:32:26.197 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
web_1  |
web_1  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:15) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
web_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
web_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    ... 36 common frames omitted
web_1  | Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
web_1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  | Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
web_1  |    ... 4 common frames omitted
web_1  | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:149) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.jdbc42.AbstractJdbc42Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc42Connection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.jdbc42.Jdbc42Connection.<init>(Jdbc42Connection.java:28) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:415) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
web_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
web_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
web_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
web_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
web_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
web_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
web_1  |    ... 18 common frames omitted
web_1  | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres
web_1  |    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:129) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar!/:9.4]
web_1  |    ... 37 common frames omitted
web_1  |
demo_web_1 exited with code 1
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: you have to setup host file to make `postgres=localhost`

Comment: postgres host should be set to `db` in your case.

Comment: @michalk how would I do that?

Comment: Most likely in your springboot app properties file.